# How to add external data in a associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, associative-array

I'm having a problem in adding another data inside a array I really don't know on how to pass it on. Here is my code.

```
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($q->result() as $rows){
            $data[] = $rows;                
        }
        $data[]['in'] = 'IN';
    }
```

How can I add `IN` inside the array. Because it gives me this.

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
     [rstatus] => Unavailable
        [rprice] => 5000
    )

 [1] => IN
 )
```

I want it to be like.

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
     [rstatus] => Unavailable
     [rprice] => 5000
    [in] => IN
    )
```

Comment: what language are you working with?

Comment: i'm using php codeigniter

Comment: In the future, you should always tag the language. It will be viewed my more people who are watching for the php tag. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($q->result() as $rows) { 
        if (!isset($rows->in)) {           
          $rows->in = 'IN';            
        }
        $data[] = $rows;                
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns me this error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`

Comment: Sorry - I should have noticed you were dealing with an object, revised.